# Should Prometheus Java simpleclient Custom Collector metrics be instantiated on every collection?

Tags: java, prometheus

In the [simpleclient Java README](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#custom-collectors) the example `Collector` looks like this:

```
class YourCustomCollector extends Collector {
  List<MetricFamilySamples> collect() {
    List<MetricFamilySamples> mfs = new ArrayList<MetricFamilySamples>();
    // With no labels.
    mfs.add(new GaugeMetricFamily("my_gauge", "help", 42));
    // With labels
    GaugeMetricFamily labeledGauge = new GaugeMetricFamily("my_other_gauge", "help", Arrays.asList("labelname"));
    labeledGauge.addMetric(Arrays.asList("foo"), 4);
    labeledGauge.addMetric(Arrays.asList("bar"), 5);
    mfs.add(labeledGauge);
    return mfs;
  }
}

// Registration
static final YourCustomCollector requests = new YourCustomCollector().register()
```

Must the metrics be instantiated on every call to `collect` or would it be reasonable to instantiate them once and then just call `addMetric` in `collect`? If not, what would be the problem of this approach?

Comment: Hi, but these are different objects that are getting collected, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, MetricFamilies should (almost) always be instantiated anew on each collect.

> would it be reasonable to instantiate them once and then just call addMetric in collect?

That wouldn't be thread-safe, and you'd also need to do something to clear it across collections.